# Bug on wordpress TwentyFifteen theme? Sidebar won't scroll

Tags: wordpress

Having problems with the sidebar on my site.

It won't scroll. (in Mac Chrome and Mac Firefox -- and maybe in other browsers)

I've had it fixed a couple of times. But it keeps breaking.

The last time, the developer said wordpress version and plugins need to be up to date.

I've updated them. Still same problem.

I've had quite a few customisations, so I don't want to just change the theme unless necessary.

This is the site: http://richardclunan.com

Is this a bug in the TwentyFifteen theme?

Is there a fix for it?

Comment: I can see your <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar" style="position: fixed;">. Just remove  style="position: fixed;".

Comment: You forget your question? I'm still here wait for help you...

Comment: thanks Quỳnh Nguyễn -- just seen your comment. I'll send my developer a link to the thread. appreciate your help -- cheers.